# How can I tell what version of Might and Magic: Heroes 6 is installed using Steam?

Tags: steam, might-and-magic-heroes-6

Is there any way I can check what version (for example v1.0.2) of Might and Magic: Heroes 6 is currently installed via the Steam client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the version of the game, you can find it in the main menu in the lower right/left corner.

However, be aware that Steam does not patch Heroes 6.

It's patchable through the Ubisoft Installer application which in turn is installed by Steam when it enters the prerequisite stage of the game installation phase. Whenever you launch HOMM 6 via Steam it automatically launches the Ubisoft application which checks if there is a new patch.

Comment: Thanks! It does seem however, that you do have to verify the game cache after each ubisoft update

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question 'How can I tell what version of a game is installed using Steam?', as it is specific to a single game.

Comment: @mikemaccana The question is really just asking about HOMM6, although it's poorly worded. I've updated the question (and title) to make this more clear.

Comment: @Wipqozn Fair enough. I wanted to find out what version of another game was installed, but I can ask a separate question.